# javascript + e4x: how to test if an element is empty?

Tags: javascript, xml, e4x

Is there a way to test whether an XML element is empty using e4x?

e.g. if I have an element `<foo />`, I want to return true, but if I have another element that has any attributes, child elements, or text, I want to return false.

Answer (score 2):

I just slogged through the [ECMA-357 v2 spec on e4x](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-357.htm); the methods for XML nodes are listed in section 13.4.4, and there are no useful `isXXX()` or `hasXXX()` methods for this test; the simplest way to do it seems to be the following:

```
function isEmptyNode(node){ 
  return node.children().length() == 0 && node.attributes().length() == 0;
}
```